# Route variable not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Why doesn't this simple route work?

```
Route::get('/test/{id?}', function ($id = 1) {
    return view('test');
});
```

This is the content in "test" view (test.blade.php):

```
This is a test: {{ $id }}.
```

If I enter:

```
http://laravel.test/test
```

or

```
http://laravel.test/test/1
```

I always get this error:

```
This is a test: <?php echo e($id); ?>.

"Undefined variable: id (View: /home/vagrant/code/test/resources/views/test.blade.php)"
```

Comment: `'/test/{id?}'` I think you need to remove the question mark?

Comment: @Malovich it doesn't work either

Comment: You need to pass the variable to the view. https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route parameters are not automatically available in views unless you explicitly pass it to the view. This adjustment will make it available.

```
Route::get('/test/{id?}', function ($id = 1) {
    return view('test', ['id' => $id]);
});
```

Comment: So easy! Thank you!